# Text to Speech - Null pointer Exception

Tags: android, exception, pointers, null, text-to-speech

I created a TTS module. It was working perfectly on a stand alone basis but when I tried implementing it as a class for my project it misbehaves and throws null pointer exception.

What I plan to achieve:

1) Read a text file from /res/raw folder.
2) convert the text file into speech via TTS. The string s has captured the whole file via the BufferReader class.

The code I have used for TTS is -

```
private TextToSpeech tts;
tts.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

The error comes on the tts.speak..... line. I found out this line by adding log.d throughout the code. There is no log.d registered post the above tts.speak code.

Please help me in debugging the issue.

thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown *declaring* the variable:

```
private TextToSpeech tts;
```

... and you've shown *using* the variable:

```
tts.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

... but do you ever *initialize* the variable? If you don't assign it a value, it will always have the default value of `null`. Judging by [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/) you need something like this (I'm assuming your code is in an `Activity`):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you guessed it correct, the tts is being implemented as an activity. Thanks I did not initialize the variable. Will try it today. BTW the code did work on a standalone basis without initialization.

Comment: Thanks. Now I donot get the exception now but the engine does not play anything.

Comment: @user1576339: Have you read the tutorial I linked to thoroughly? (I'm not sure what you mean by "the code did work on a standalone basis without initialization" - if you call a method on a null reference you *will* get an exception...)

Comment: hi, I read the tutorial from http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html